# Get data from android string array from resource

Tags: android, arrays, string, resources

I know how to get data from `string-array`. I have done like this.

```
<string-array name="values">
   <item>value1</item>
   <item>value2</item>
</string-array>

String[] values = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.values);
```

But I dont know whether the below type `string-array` is possible and confused to get values from that.

```
<string-array name="country_data">
        <item>
            <country>Afghanistan</country>
            <countryCode>93</countryCode>
            <iso2>AF</iso2>
            <iso3>AFG</iso3>
        </item>
    </string-array>
```

If it is possible please help me to get the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I dont know whether the below type string-array is possible

It is not.

If you want to have arbitrary XML, use `res/xml/` for whatever XML structure you like. You can then use `getResources().getXml()` to get an `XmlPullParser` that you can use to parse that XML.

Or, wrap the contents of each of your `<item>` elements in `CDATA`, which should prevent the resource parser from messing with them. Then, each string you retrieve from the array would be plain XML, that you would need to parse.

Or, go with JSON in `res/raw/` or `assets/`, using your favorite JSON parser (e.g., Gson).

Or, [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to package a database in your app that has this data pre-loaded.

Or, use [R. Zagórski's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6507689/r-zag%c3%b3rski), of having one `<string-array>` per object, with `<item>` elements for each field of the object.

Comment: I preferred to go with XmlPullParser.

Answer (score 0):

xml :

```
<string-array name="_name">
        <item>n11</item>
        <item>n12</item>
        <item>n13</item>
        <item>n14</item>
        <item>n15</item>
        <item>n16</item>
    </string-array>
```

Retrieve at java class:

```
   String[] test;
test = getResources().getStringArray(R.array._name);
```

Answer (score -1):

Of course it is possible.

In summary:

1. Define POJO representing your model
2. Create a function to import string array of arrays from resources into this POJO

Remember that you cannot use custom xml entries, they have to be `<item>`. And you need to know it's type upfront.